# :after pseudo element is not showing up

Tags: html, css

I have simplified my question to this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="dropbox">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.dropbox {
    border:2px solid #ff0000;
    height:200px;
    width:50%;
    margin:auto;
}
.dropbox:after {
    content:'';
    width:10px;
    height:10px;
    background:#ff0000;
    top:100%;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:5px;
}
```

Why can't I get the `:after` pseudo element to show up?

I need it at the bottom middle of the div. To by clear, it should be under the div in the middle.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's worth noting that the pseudo element is `inline` by default - you therefore can't add margins or change the dimensions of it. If you were to change the display to `block` you will notice that it shows up as you would expect [**(example)**](http://jsfiddle.net/GL6pS/1/).

In your case you need to absolutely position it *relative* to the parent element.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/GL6pS/)

```
.dropbox {
    border:2px solid #ff0000;
    height:200px;
    width:50%;
    margin:auto;
    position:relative;
}
.dropbox:after {
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    width:10px;
    height:10px;
    background:#ff0000;
    top:100%;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:5px;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm guessing that the default display for the pseudo :after element is inline. Because the :after element has no content it shrinks to nothing.

Set `display:block` then your width & height apply and you can see your element.

```
.dropbox:after {
    content:'';
    width:10px;
    height:10px;
    background:#ff0000;
    top:100%;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:5px;
    display: block
}
```